# Sorting file horizontally in linux lexicographic

Tags: linux, sort

I have a file like below having multiple rows and columns,

```
a x1.1 x1.2 x1.10 x1.11
```

I wanted to do lexicographic sorting in columns started from 2nd in the file. So that, output in each row should be,

```
a x1.1 x1.10 x1.11 x1.2
```

I used, `LC_ALL=C sort /path_to_file/file` but it don't give desired output.
For example, for multiple lines,

```
input
a x1.1 x1.2 x1.10 x1.11
b x1.2 x1.3 x1.10 x1.11
a x1.10 x1.20 x1.13 1.12

desired output
a x1.1 x1.10 x1.11 x1.2
b x1.10 x1.11 x1.2 x1.3
a x1.10 x1.12 x1.13 x1.20

getting output
a x1.1 x1.2 x1.10 x1.11
a x1.10 x1.20 x1.13 x1.12
b x1.2 x1.2 x1.10 x1.11
```

Please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Perl:

```
$ perl -alpe '$_ = join " ", shift @F, sort @F' input
a x1.1 x1.10 x1.11 x1.2
b x1.10 x1.11 x1.2 x1.3
a x1.10 x1.12 x1.13 x1.20
```

The script loops over lines of input. `-a` causes input lines to be split on whitespace, into default array `@F`. `shift @F` slices off the 0th element (to exclude it from the sort), then `sort @F` sorts the remaining elements - lexicographicaly by default. The `join " ", ...` stitches the result back together, separated by the space character.

I *think* that Perl's `sort` ignores your locale by default so you get `LC_COLLATE=C` for free.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working correctly. But, I am not able to understand this command. Can you please give a brief explanation of it? Or a reference document?

Comment: @AdityaParikh please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @steeldriver